# Why does this regex not match this color in Java?

Tags: java, regex, hex

The commonly found regex for hex color code matches the color **#79bff7** just fine, but it fails inside my Java program.

The color validator I've used is just a copy of [HexValidator](https://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-hex-color-code-with-regular-expression/).

```java
public class HexValidator{

   private Pattern pattern;
   private Matcher matcher;

   private static final String HEX_PATTERN = "^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$";

   public HexValidator(){
      pattern = Pattern.compile(HEX_PATTERN);
   }

   /**
   * Validate hex with regular expression
   * @param hex hex for validation
   * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
   */
   public boolean validate(final String hex){

      matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
      return matcher.matches();

   }
}
```

I'd like to see that specific color matching just like it does on online regex matchers like [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: it is matching that color code for me `new HexValidator().validate("#79bff7")` results in `true`; while `new HexValidator().validate("ups")` is `false` maybe a [mcve] would show what is wrong... BTW since using `matches` there is no need for `^` and `$`

Comment: Yeah it seems to work fine for me. Maybe verify your input for typos?

Comment: **BTW2**  `regex101` does not have the Java Flavor (little differences?, sure not a problem for not-too-complicated expressions) unlike [RegexPlanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/) or [Online regex tester](http://myregexp.com/); **BTW3** the given expression only works if the whole string matches, that is, if there is some extra space, punctuation, character,... anywhere it will fail  **BTW4** para português: [pt.so]

Comment: Works fine at my end!

Comment: Odds are that `#79bff7` is not your real string. There could be whitespace and/or zero-width chars somewhere.

Comment: Try to print the _hex_ string inside Validator().

Answer (score 0):

Print a message when it does not match.  Include the quotes so you can see if there are any spaces.

```
public boolean validate(final String hex){
   matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
   boolean matches = matcher.matches();
   if (!matches)
       System.out.println ("not a hex color string: \"" + hex + "\" length: " + hex.length());
   return matches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have whitespace/non-printable chars outside the color text, you could use this regex and `Matcher.find` instead:

```java
private static final String HEX_PATTERN =
    "(?i)#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3})(?![a-f0-9])";

public boolean validate(final String hex) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

This regex could also be used if you want to scan for multiple colors in a string.

Answer (score 0):

There was indeed some spaces within the color code. Thank you guys! I'm sorry for the lack of attention!